# Is it possible to turn a list in Haskell into a string of the elemnts within?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a small film "database" which is just a list and each element in the list is a tuple.

I would like to display the list in a string as an easy to read format so for example each data item in the list should be displayed as follows:

```
Casino Royale
Daniel Craig, Eva Green
2006
Garry, Dave

Titanic
Leonardo DiCaprio, Kate Winslet
1997
Zoe, Amy
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
type Title = String
type Actors = [String]
type Year = Int
type Fans = [String]
type Film = (Title, Actors, Year, Fans)
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green"], 2006,["Garry", "Dave"]),
                ("Titanic", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet"], 1997, ["Zoe", "Amy"]),
....
]
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Just write a function `prettyPrintDB :: Database -> String`, then you can do `putStrLn $ prettyPrintDB testDatabase` to print it to the screen.  It might be easier to also write `prettyPrint` functions for your other types so that you can combine them together to write `prettyPrintDB`.

Comment: I don't really understand how to do that, sorry, I am very new to Haskell so I will be struggling

Comment: Start by implementing `prettyPrintTitle :: Title -> String`.  For this, the implementation should be really simple since the title is already in the format you want.  Then do `prettyPrintActors :: Actors -> String` which turns a list of strings into a comma separated string (look at `Data.List.intercalate`).  Do the same for `Year` and `Fans`, then you can write `prettyPrintFilm :: Film -> String`; `prettyPrintFilm (t, a, y, f) = unlines [prettyPrintTitle t, prettyPrintActors a, prettyPrintYear y, prettyPrintFans f]`.  Finally, `prettyPrintDB = unlines . map prettyPrintFilm`.

Comment: `pp :: Film -> String; 
pp (t,a,y,f) = i "\n" [t, i ", " a, show y, i ", " f]
    where i x = intercalate x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to produce the outcome that I wanted by using @karakfa's approach in the comments of the original post:

```
pp :: Film -> String; pp (t,a,y,f) = i "\n" [t, i ", " a, show y, i ", " f] where i x = intercalate x
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write your own `Show` instance for `Film`. But you need to enable some extensions:

```
{-#LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances#-}
{-#LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances#-}
{-#LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances#-}
```

Then you create an instance of `Show`:

```
instance Show Film where
    show (t,a,y,f) = t ++ "\n" ++ actors ++ "\n" ++ (show y) ++ "\n" ++ fans
        where actors = intercalate ", " a
              fans = intercalate ", "  f
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> mapM_ (\x -> (putStrLn $ show x) >> putStrLn "") testDatabase
Casino Royale
Daniel Craig, Eva Green
2006
Garry, Dave

Titanic
Leonardo DiCaprio, Kate Winslet
1997
Zoe, Amy
```

I would suggest you to break your `(a,b,c,d)` type to a record data structure. That is more preferable.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the extensions and without using instance?

Comment: @AdamPiper You can use the bheklir's approach for that.

Comment: Yes, just use your own types instead of type synonyms.